# Meteor: Uploading an image and saving to the database as base64 string

Tags: image, meteor, base64, image-uploading

I have a Meteor app and I am interested in getting image upload to work in the simplest possible manner.

The simplest manner I can come up with is to somehow convert the image to a base64 string on the client and the save it to the database as a string.

How is it possible to convert an image on the users filesystem to a base64 string and then save it to the database?

Comment: How about saving the image on server. can anyone post a working code ? I was trying to use ImageCollection.write function and failed. Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an HTML5 file input :

HTML

```
<template name="fileUpload">
  <form>
    <input type="file" name="imageFile">
    <button type="submit" disabled={{submitDisabled}}>
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Then listen to the change event and use a `FileReader` to read the local file as a base64 data url that we're going to store in a reactive var :

```
Template.fileUpload.created=function(){
  this.dataUrl=new ReactiveVar();
};

Template.fileUpload.events({
  "change input[type='file']":function(event,template){
    var files=event.target.files;
    if(files.length===0){
      return;
    }
    var file=files[0];
    //
    var fileReader=new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload=function(event){
      var dataUrl=event.target.result;
      template.dataUrl.set(dataUrl);
    });
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});
```

Then we can use the reactive var value to allow/disallow form submission and send the value to the server :

```
Template.fileUpload.helpers({
  submitDisabled:function(){
    return Template.instance().dataUrl.get();
  }
});

Template.fileUpload.events({
  "submit":function(event,template){
    event.preventDefault();
    //
    Meteor.call("uploadImage",template.dataUrl.get());
  }
});
```

You will need to define a server method that saves the `dataUrl` to some collection field value, what's cool about `dataUrl`s is that you can use them directly as an image tag `src`.

Note that this solution is highly unscalable as the image data won't be cachable and will pollute the app database regular communications (which should only contain text-like values).

You could fetch the base64 data from the `dataUrl` and upload it to Google Cloud Storage or Amazon S3 and serve the files behind a CDN.

You could also use services that do all of this stuff for you like uploadcare or filepicker.

EDIT :

This solution is easy to implement but comes with the main drawback that fetching large base64 strings from mongodb will slow your app from fetching other data, DDP communications are always live and not cachable at the moment so your app will always redownload image data from the server.

You wouldn't save `dataUrl`s to Amazon, you would save the image directly, and it would be fetched by your app using an Amazon URL with a cachable HTTP request.

You have two choices when it comes to file upload : you can upload them directly from the client using specific javascript browser APIs or you can upload them within Node.js (NPM modules) APIs in the server.

In the case you want to upload from the server (which is usually simpler because you don't need to require that the users of your apps authenticate against third party services, only your server will act as a trusted client to communicate with Amazon API), then you can send the data that a user want to upload through a method call with a `dataUrl` as argument.

If you don't want to dive into all this stuff consider using uploadcare or filepicker, but keep in mind that these are paid services (as is Amazon S3 BTW).

Comment: ah thanks for your response and the comment about scaling. I didn't know, the reason I wanted to use base64 is because I would not have to deal with uploading a file and saving it to amazon and getting a link to the file back. I thought this would be easy since I can treat the image the same as any data and populate the page with it using img src. So I guess your recommendation of storing the string on amazon s3 or something would work. It would still be easier than transferring the actual image file. I wonder where I can store and retrieve string values, nearly free and fast?

Comment: This would make no sense to store dataUrl on Amazon S3, see my edit.

Comment: How to get multiple files and its dataUrl in base64?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you can easily do this with a file reader. In the Template event handler where you get the file contents, you can pass the file to the reader and get back a base64 string. For example, something like this:

```
Template.example.events({
  'submit form': function (event, template) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = template.find('#fileUpload').files[0]; // get the file

    reader.onload = function (event) {
      // event.target.result is the base64 string
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});
```